# playing audio from Application in blackberry?

Tags: audio, blackberry

I want to play audio from my application. the following code is used

```
 try{
     Player p = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer("file:///store/home/user/recording.amr");
     p.realize();

     VolumeControl volume = (VolumeControl) p.getControl("VolumeControl");
     volume.setLevel(30);

      p.prefetch();
      p.start();
    }catch(MediaException me)
    {
        Dialog.alert(me.toString());
    } 
    catch(IOException ioe) 
    {
        Dialog.alert(ioe.toString());
    }
```

then i get an exception net.rim.device.internal.media.rimmediaexception : Media unloded while initializing

Any idea about this exception?

Comment: this looks like it should be working, is there a specific model or OS version you are having trouble with?

Comment: Will the audio play if you try to use the default BB media player?  It's possible the file has some problem with it.

Comment: i play the file using default media player. it works fine. i using the device bb perl 9105 with osv5.0.0.831.

Comment: is the file really short, 2 seconds or less? If so, can you confirm if a longer file plays ok?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read the rim article: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11941/BlackBerry_Java_Application-Development_Guide--741609-1109114520-001-5.0_Beta-US.pdf

Refer thw stack ovewr flow link [Radio Streaming in Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5577795/658976.I)

Comment: Can also refer http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17968/Play_audio_in_a_BB_device_app_1222359_11.jsp

Comment: If you run using u r phone ,make sure you remove the usb code form your mobile.